# How can i do same credit style in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image: demo image]

How can i do same credit style in flutter, anyone can help me? 
I just need only Formfield. If i found all the Formfield. I can customize all the fields text.
Thanks ❤️

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you OR you can use Some Dependency [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_credit_card) or [here](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_card) for payments Card

Used packages

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Create **Widget** for Your Design

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height:30),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20,
             
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                CardNumberFormatter(),
              ],
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX',
                labelText: 'Card Number',
              ),
              maxLength: 19,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20,
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Name',
                hintText: 'Card Holder Name',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      DateFormatter(),
                    ],
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Card Expiry',
                        labelText: 'MM/YY'),
                    maxLength: 5,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                Flexible(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'CVV',
                      hintText: 'CVV Number',
                    ),
                    maxLength: 3,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Pay'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Create a class for **Card Number Validation**

```
class CardNumberFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue previousValue,
    TextEditingValue nextValue,
  ) {
    var inputText = nextValue.text;

    if (nextValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return nextValue;
    }

    var bufferString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
      bufferString.write(inputText[i]);
      var nonZeroIndexValue = i + 1;
      if (nonZeroIndexValue % 4 == 0 && nonZeroIndexValue != inputText.length) {
        bufferString.write(' ');
      }
    }

    var string = bufferString.toString();
    return nextValue.copyWith(
      text: string,
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: string.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Create a Class for **Date Validation**

```
class DateFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    var text = newValue.text;

    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return newValue;
    }

    var buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      buffer.write(text[i]);
      var nonZeroIndex = i + 1;
      if (nonZeroIndex % 2 == 0 && nonZeroIndex != text.length) {
        buffer.write('/');
      }
    }

    var string = buffer.toString();
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: string,
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: string.length));
  }
}
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: https://ibb.co/qDyJb7n how can i remove this maxLenth text.

Comment: just remove maxLenth  in CardWidget,DateWidget and CVV Widget

Comment: that's work,                        counterText: '',
when i use this.

Comment: Your problem is Solved?

Comment: No brother, there some problem in Expiry date field, can you help me how can I do - ''4/6/2031'' this style

Comment: I Will try and let you know,Wait

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833230/13997210) answer for your date format validation

Comment: this is not working, when i type number there nothing show in field.