# Flutter input DOB without datePicker

Tags: flutter, datetime

I have a form where a user puts in his/her Date of Birth. However, I don't want to user DatePicker. I want that when a user puts in a number (say the "date") it should move automatically to the next field (say the "Month") and so on.

Something like this

```
DOB: DD/MM/YYYY
```

Is it possible for flutter?
And how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, but this is just my opinion. First, call the `onChanged`method in your textfiled like this.

```
TextFormField(
          controller: _DOBTextController,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'mm/dd/yyyy'),
          onChanged: (value) {
             if(value.length != 10){
               //check text length is equal to 2 or 5 add backspace 
               if(value.length == 2 || value.length == 5) {
                 value = '$value/';
                _DOBTextController.value = TextEditingValue(text: 
                value,selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 
                value.length),);
                } 
               }
              },
          
                      
        ),
```

After that add `final _DOBTextController = TextEditingController();` top of your class. I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks. It kinda helped. Deleting it in case of a mistake creates a kind of problem. It doesn't delete because of the "/" value which it not from the TexteditingController.
Also, since it's date, how do I limit the "mm" and "dd" to their respective values they contain? That is "dd" can only have a max of 31 days why "mm" only has 12 months.

Comment: @EBENEZEROCANSEY check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833230/20259506) answer. I think this should be what you are looking for.